# ESB Toolkit 2.1 error: "Could not enlist Send Port 'ALL.Exceptions'..."

Tags: biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010

I reinstalled the ESB toolkit using the same process (painful) that worked twice before.

But now when I go try to start the BizTalk application "Microsoft.Practices.ESB" in the BizTalk Administration Console, the application fails to start showing the following error:

```
Could not enlist Send Port 'ALL.Exceptions'. 
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE557 (Microsoft.BizTalk.SnapIn.Framework)
```

I found this error message in the event log:

> Unable to communicate with MessageBox BizTalkMsgBoxDb on SQL Instance [MY SERVER]. 
>   
> Error Code: 0x8004d00e. 
> Possible reasons include: 
>    1) The MessageBox is unavailable.
>    2) The network link from this machine to the MessageBox is down.
>    3) The DTC Configuration on either this local machine or the machine hosting this MessageBox is incorrect.

SQL Server seems to be running ok. Really don't know where to start looking...

Comment: I found also the following:

"The Biztalk Service BizTalk Group: BiztalkServerApplication" was set to auto but was not started (probably because of the SQL access problem)

I configured the DTC according to this MSDN  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544733%28CS.70%29.aspx) but still get the same errors...

This ESB Toolkit sure is a very premature product...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. Check out the port's filters, if the list is empty try to manually configure the filters on the port as following:
ErrorReport.FailureCode - Exists
Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ExceptionHandling.Schemas.Property.FaultCode - exists
those are the filters that usually exists on this port and somehow disappeared.

Worked for me, hope it will work for u as well

best regards,
David

Comment: :Thanks a lot. I have used this solution in more than one case. A very important solution.

Comment: Could be a problem with the binding file: http://jeremyronk.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/could-not-enlist-send-port-send-port-name-exception-from-hresult-0xc00ce557microsoft-biztalk-explorerom/

Comment: Thanks David, the filters were missing following my installation too

Comment: Thanks, M.Travis Volker. I would have never thought of that!

Comment: In my case I copy-pasted text from binding file into BTDF PortBindingsMaster.xml file, and doing so, Visual Studio added newline before filter specification. It was NOT related to what I was doing, so finding it was not easy. Worth documenting on stackoverflow.com!